# trouble finding a specific item from mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a code that I am following on a tutorial. I am trying to retrieve a specific article from the database using its title but I am not able to retrieve anything and there is no error. Retrieving all the articles works, it's just retrieving a specific article that's the problem.
For example, http://localhost:3000/articles/{TITLE} doesn't work and the site just hangs waiting for a response which never comes.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const articleSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

// Requests Targeting All Routes

app.route("/articles")

.get(function(req, res) {
    Article.find()
        .then((foundArticles) => {
            mongoose.connection.close();
            foundArticles.forEach(function(foundArticle) {
                // console.log(foundArticle);
                res.send(foundArticles);
            })
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})

.post(function(req, res) {
    const newArticle = new Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    });

    newArticle.save()
        .then(function() {
            res.send("Successfully added a new article.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})

.delete(function(req, res) {
    Article.deleteMany()
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Successfully deleted the document.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
});

// Requests Targeting Specific Routes
// This is the one that is creating the problem.

app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
.get(function(req, res) {
    Article.find()
        .then({title: req.query.articleTitle}, (foundArticle)  => {
            res.send(foundArticle);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000!");
});
```

The database is in this format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6517a22854d8425f4e613d9e"),
    "title" : "REST",
    "content" : "REST is short for REpresentational State Transfer. It's an architectural style for designing APIs."
}
```

Since I don't get an error, I don't know what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### a quickly fix solution

> You must use the `params` to get the router arguments.

```js
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle").get(function(req, res) {
  // req.params ✅
  const title = req.params.articleTitle;
  Article.find()
    // There is a bug in the code here ❌
    .then({title}, (foundArticle) => {
      res.send(foundArticle);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
});
```

> update, fix: the mongoose.js API usage error

```js
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
.get(async (req, res) => {
  // req.params ✅
  const title = req.params.articleTitle;
  // async await ✅
  const article = await Article.findOne({title});
  res.json({
    article
  });
});
```

```js
// or
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
.get((req, res) => {
  // req.params ✅
  const title = req.params.articleTitle;
  Article.findOne({title})
  // promise ✅
  .then((article) => {
    res.json({
      article
    });
    // res.send(article);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

### refs

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find()

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOne()

Comment: Should be `Article.find({title}).then((foundArticle) => {res.send({foundArticle});})` The `{title}` needs to be the query object.

Comment: It is important to put {title} in Article.find(). Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: That's just copied from your code.